# 2 externals monitors on dell e6510 (nvida 3100m)

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dell-latitude

I have laptop dell lattitude e6510.
It has nvidia 3100m display chip.
System is Windows 7 x64 and I've installed the newest drivers from dell.

I can't run required configuration: work on 2 external monitors. One is DSub connected to laptop and the other is DVI connected through DisplyPort->DVI adapter. When I connect monitors like above I have desktop visible on laptop monitor and on DSub monitor. I can't change it to show on both external monitors. When I enter into "Screen resolutions" window I can't detect there the monitor connected through DP->DVI adapter. Adapter itself is running well as I tried to connect it to another dell laptop with different graphics card the monitor showed at once after connecting. This dell is precision m4500 with nvidia quadro fx 1800m.

What should I setup somewhere?

Comment: what's the problem? Expand on what's happening, because At this point possibilities to numerous to list.

Comment: I extended problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred that the laptop was damaged. Other one (same model) was working well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you have those possible problems:

1. Bad connection to Monitor. Check all cables are connected properly. Probability: low
2. External monitor is not recognized as it's not set to DVI source. Turn it on and force DVI as source in monitor menu, if this is a model with both VGA/DVI input (most have auto detect, but this may not work well). Probability: low
3. You need to install Dell Nvidia drivers. Unfortunately a lot of problems like this are caused by Nvidia drivers. Download drivers for your laptop from Dell Website, uninstall current ones, install Dell drivers. Probability: high.
4. You need to connect the monitor while logged onto Windows. Additionally, try to connect it as only external display (that is: disconnect VGA one first). probability: medium
5. Your DP>DVI adapter is Dell-incompatible. More often than not Dell laptops work well with Genuine Dell adapters only. Probability: very high.

Comment: 1. The same DVI monitor using the same cable is working on another PC.
2. This is the point I don't understand. What should I set to HDMI? I don't use HDMI at all.
3. I've already installed nvidia drivers downloaded from dell site
4. I conntected monitor while logged into Windows and this was the first monitor connected.
5. I checked adapter on another DELL laptop (different graphics card) and it works

Comment: Oh, sorry. Substitute DVI for HDMI in my reply. Correcting now. As for drivers - did you uninstall and remove old ones first? If not, do that. Also - try to install first version of the Dell drivers first, not the last one. I know - Dell is a bitch to set up sometimes. What other Dell Laptop is this?

Comment: I've installed this driver http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=R287174   How can I get older one?

Comment: added info about the second dell where all worked ok

Comment: Look here. I would recommend going for one of the "Driver Packs", as they are made available "as is" and aren't updated. http://downloads.dell.com/published/pages/latitude-e6510.html

Comment: All your additional information would point to E6510 graphics card. However: it has discrete graphics card, but does it have also Intel integrated HD graphics? it is possible there is a conflict between the two: VGA is ran through Intel, while Displayport through Nvidia. I don't know, as I have limited exposure to e6500 line... Drivers are usually crucial there, especially with Optimus technology.

Comment: In our company we have 3 similar laptops. And only mine is not working with required configuration - looks like display port not working at all. I played with drivers and no result. Should I turn off Optimus technology? Or turn on? And how?

Comment: At this point I'd say it's a case for Dell Customer Support. Especially with your impression that the DP is not working at all. DisplayPort usually gives problem with audio, but it's not that troublesome. Unless you try one more thing: force use of Nvidia adapter only. Sorry, don't remember how to do that exactly now.

Answer (score 0):

I tested that you can extend the desktop of a Dell Latitude E6510 on two external monitors if using a DELL PR02X docking station (and most probably with a DELL PR03X docking station as well). The PR02X is the wide model and the PR03X is the narrow one.
The tests were performed with the "default" Intel GMA graphics, but it should also work when the laptop comes with the NVIDIA graphic chip.

Maybe having the NVIDIA 3100M you can connect two external monitors without using a docking station, but I'm not sure however. A computer having several graphical ports doesn't mean that you can use them at the same time.

As the user AcePL mentioned, you must install the NVIDIA drivers.
I would suggest downloading them from Dell's website if they're available ; else, visit Nvidia's website.